# Windows 10 Host cannot access SQL Server on Oracle Virtual Box

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, virtualbox, biztalk

I have created a VM with virtual box that runs windows 10, and installed SQL Server.

Using Consume Adapter Service in Visual Studio for BizTalk 2020

Configured: SQLBinding AS: mssql://DESKTOP-T2G7B3A/MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER/AFBizTalkTest?InboundId=ID

Click Connect:

> Failure 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified

Items tried or checked:

1. Ran PortQry on Virtual Box:

   ```
    Starting portqry.exe -n 10.0.2.15 -e 1433 -p TCP ...

    Querying target system called:
    10.0.2.15

    Attempting to resolve IP address to a name...

    IP address resolved to DESKTOP-T2G7B3A

    querying...
    TCP port 1433 (ms-sql-s service): LISTENING

    portqry.exe -n 10.0.2.15 -e 1433 -p TCP exits with return code 0x00000000.
   ```

1A. Ran PortQry On Host

```
     Starting portqry.exe -n 10.0.2.15 -e 1433 -p TCP ...

     Querying target system called:
     10.0.2.15

     Attempting to resolve IP address to a name...

     Failed to resolve IP address to name

     querying...

     TCP port 1433 (ms-sql-s service): FILTERED

     portqry.exe -n 10.0.2.15 -e 1433 -p TCP exits with return code 0x00000002.
```

1B. Verified the IP address on Virtual Box is 10.0.2.15. Failed to ping on Host, Successful ping on Virtual Box.

3. TCP/IP Enabled in SQL Server instance.
4. Changed Server name to ip address  - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified
5. Verified SQL Server Browser is running.
6. Verified Server Name from Error Log.

Comment: Do you have SQL Management Studio installed.  If you connect from there to the Server Instance  DESKTOP-T2G7B3A\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER does it work?

Comment: "The return code 0x00000002 means there is no response from the UDP port. It seems like the UDP port 53 is opened but there is no service listening or there is a firewall in the way"

Comment: I can run  management studio on the vm, no problem, but when I run it from my host I get the server cannot be found or is not accessible..

Comment: `Error Locating Server/Instance Specified` indicates that the SQL Browser Service isn't reachable on udp/1434. This is used to convert your instance name, `MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER`, into a TCP port number that the client can then connect to. Since (I assume) you already know that the port number is 1433, have you tried to use `mssql://DESKTOP-T2G7B3A//AFBizTalkTest?InboundId=ID` or `mssql://DESKTOP-T2G7B3A:1433//AFBizTalkTest?InboundId=ID`?